# JS: Using i as an Index of a String in a Loop Is Returning an Integer, Not the Letter

Tags: javascript

Learning JS/programming and running through some basic exercises.

This one is to determine if a word is a palindrome (reads the same forwards as backwards).

My problem is that the function is returning `false` even when I input a palindrome. From looking at it stepping over, it seems `string[i`] is giving an integer to compare, instead of the character at that current index.

```js
let input = "hannah";
let firstCharacter = input[0];
let lastIndex = input.length -1;
let lastCharacter = input[lastIndex];


function palTest(string) {
 let j = string[lastIndex];
 if (string.length % 2 === 0 )
 {
  for (i = 0; i <= string.length / 2; i++) {
   if (string[i] === string[j]) {
    j--;
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  } 
 } else {
  let middleCharacter = (string.length + 1) / 2;
  for (i = 0; i <= ((string.length + 1) / 2) - 1; i++) {
   if (string[i] === string[j] && middleCharacter == "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" ) {
    j--;
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  } 
 }
}

let x = palTest(input);
console.log(x); // false
console.log(input[0]); // h
console.log(input[1]); // a
console.log(input[2]); // n
console.log(input[3]); // n
console.log(input[4]); // a
console.log(input[5]); // h
```

Inside the `for` loop on the first loop, `hannah[i]` is, I think, `0` instead of `"h"`: so it's comparing `0` to `"h"` (`hannah[j]`) and returning false?

Comment: `middleCharacter` is an integer in your code, yes. `string[middleCharacter]` would be a character.

Comment: what do you want to check with the vowels?

Comment: 1. `let j = string[lastIndex];`, instead use `let j = string.length - 1`; return true only after the end of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- no need to differ of strings with odd or even length, by using an approach with counting from start and from end,
- only one loop,
- take the index until the middle of the string,
- check if unequal then exit function with `false`,
- if end of function is reached, return with `true`, because the string is a palindrome.

```js
function palTest(string) {
    var i, l;
    for (i = 0, l = Math.floor(string.length / 2); i < l; i++) {
        if (string[i] !== string[string.length - 1 - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(palTest('hannah'));
console.log(palTest('foo'));
```

BTW, a check with this pattern,

```
middleCharacter == "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"
```

checks only the first part with the comparison and if not `true`, the next string `"e"` is taken as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value as return value of the condition.

At all, there happens no real check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **decrement lastIndex instead of value at last index**

```js
function palTest(string) {
  var lastIndex = string.length - 1; //initialize lastIndex here
  let j = string[lastIndex];
  if (string.length % 2 === 0) {
    for (i = 0; i <= string.length / 2; i++) {
      if (string[i] === string[lastIndex]) { //compare with lastIndex
        lastIndex--; //decrement last index
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    let middleCharacter = (string.length + 1) / 2;
    for (i = 0; i <= ((string.length + 1) / 2) - 1; i++) {
      if (string[i] === string[lastIndex] && middleCharacter == "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") {
        lastIndex--;
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log( palTest("hannah") );
console.log( palTest("hantnah") );
console.log( palTest("Not a palindrome") );
```

**A less verbose method could be**

```
var input = "hannah";
var fnCheckPal = ( input ) => input == input.split( "" ).reverse().join("");
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnCheckPal = (input) => input == input.split("").reverse().join("");

console.log( fnCheckPal( "hannah" ) );
console.log( fnCheckPal( "hantnah" ) );
console.log( fnCheckPal( "hann33ah" ) );
```

Comment: Damn that's a much neater way to check for palindromes. So simple. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simplifying your logic a bit, as you only need one loop, one variable and no global stored things for this. Just loops once, check if the current index equals the same index from the end and if it's not, it's not a palindrome. Even or uneven amount of letters don't even make a difference here:

```js
function testPalindrome( string ){
  
  for( let i = 0; i < string.length / 2; i++ ){
    
    if( string[ i ] !== string[ string.length - 1 - i ] ){
      
      return false;
      
    };
    
  }
  
  return true;
  
}

console.log( testPalindrome( 'hannah' ) ); // true
console.log( testPalindrome( 'aba' ) ); // true
console.log( testPalindrome( 'stackoverflow' ) ); // false
```